# popoverPresentationController displaying modally from UITableViewController on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm having an issue displaying a `UIViewController` with a popover presentation from iPhone within a `UITableViewController`. The code I have been using works to display a popover from any other `UIViewController`, just not a `UITableViewController` on iPhone. It does work from a `UITableViewController` on iPad.

When the code is executed, the view is presented modally temporarily (as you might expect if I did not implement `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController`) and then covered by black, as if some sort of Auto Layout error occurred (though there's nothing in the console to indicate otherwise).

As I mentioned, the following works outside of a `UITableViewController` on iPhone, and works all the time on iPad. I'm sure I'm missing something fairly simple. Any ideas?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /* Create label */
    UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
    label.text = @"This should be in a popover.";
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    /* Add label to new ViewController */
    UIViewController *popoverVC = [UIViewController new];
    [popoverVC.view addSubview:label];
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [popoverVC.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[label]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];
    [popoverVC.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[label]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];

    /* Define ViewController to present as a popover and display */
    popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    popoverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 50);
    [self presentViewController:popoverVC animated:YES completion:nil];

    /* Grab handle to ViewController's popoverPresentationController after displaying */
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverController = [popoverVC popoverPresentationController];
    if (popoverController == nil)
        NSLog(@"popoverController is nil");
    else {
        popoverController.delegate = self;
        popoverController.popoverLayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 15, 15, 15);
        popoverController.sourceView = tableView;
        popoverController.sourceRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    }
}

- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller traitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return (UIModalPresentationNone);
}
```

FWIW: One way to quickly prototype this code is to add the above to `MasterViewController.m` from a new "Master-Detail Application" template in Xcode, and define this message to avoid pushing the `DetailViewController`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    return (NO);
}
```

You'll also need to set `MasterViewController.h` to adopt the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the black color is simple.

Your controller is transparent (you have not set any background color to its `view`). The presentation animation makes it appear over the table view but once the animation ends, the views under are removed from the hierarchy and you end up with window background color (black by default) and your transparent controller with a black label.

Set

```
popoverVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

and you will see the controller behave correctly.

I am not sure why your controller is not shown as a popover because you are doing everything correctly according to the documentation. However, moving

```
[self presentViewController:popoverVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to be the last line of the method fixes the problem. Note: according to the documentation this shouldn't even work.

Comment: By the way, I used debugger command `po [[self.view window] recursiveDescription]` in popover's `viewDidAppear:` too see what's happening there.

Comment: This makes the background of the view currently appearing modal appear yellow, but the view is still modal, not a popover.

Comment: Hmm, this does seem to work, but is direct conflict with [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/) on the subject: "Configuring the popover presentation controller after calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:` might seem counter-intuitive but UIKit does not create a presentation controller until after you initiate a presentation."

Comment: @greg That's strange. I don't use popovers often so I completely forgot about this.

Comment: @greg According to the documentation my solution shouldn't work. The fact that it does makes me think they have changed something in the implementation and didn't update the documentation. Unfortunately, Apple does not use popovers a lot in their own apps so they could overlook something.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, because it *does* seem to work for `UITableViewControllers`, despite going against the documented behavior that works in all other cases. I'll see if I can get some attention on the Apple developer forums or through my existing bug report (radr://18044444).